# no feedback from the web socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

could you help me. I use websockets to create rooms. Namely, I create a rooms based on the created ID, and I transfer the same ID to the server so that it creates a new room there. And if the room was created, then I output to the console that everything was successful. The server is running on host 3000, and the site is running, but for some reason, when you click (create a room), nothing is output to the console. Why? I'm doing everything right

this is my client side:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Socket, io } from "socket.io-client";

export const useNewRoom = (roomId: string) => {
  const socketRef = useRef<Socket | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socketRef.current) {
      socketRef.current = io("http://localhost:3000");
    }

    const socket = socketRef.current;
    socket.emit("room", roomId);

    socket.on("room_created", (roomId) => {
      console.log("Room successfully created with id: ", roomId);
    });

    return () => {
      if (socket) {
        socket.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, [roomId]);
};
```

and server side:

```
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server as IOServer } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new IOServer(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
const PORT = 3000;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

io.on("connection_error", (error) => {
  console.log("Connection error: ", error);
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");

  socket.on("room", (roomId) => {
    const room = io.of('/').adapter.rooms.get(roomId);
    console.log('Room request received for room id: ' + roomId);
    if (room === undefined || room.size < 2) {
      // комната не существует или есть место
      socket.join(roomId);
      console.log(`User with ID=${socket.id} joined room=${roomId}`);
      // Отправляем событие о создании комнаты всегда после успешного присоединения к комнате
      socket.emit('room_created', roomId);
    } else {
      // комната полна
      console.log(`User with ID=${socket.id} can't join room=${roomId}, room is full`);
    }
  });
  
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
    io.of('/').adapter.rooms.forEach((value, key) => {
      if (value.has(socket.id)) {
        socket.leave(key);
        console.log(`User with ID=${socket.id} left room=${key}`);
      }
    });
  });
});

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("listening on port " + PORT);
});
```